# Javascript error closing asp.net form inside JQuery dialog iframe after postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iframe

I have an aspx page that I load into an iframe that is shown via JQuery Dialog. The page has a Cancel button that calls a "CloseMe" script that successfully closes the JQuery Dialog. The page also has a Save button that posts back.  When the data is saved, I want to close the dialog.

I have tried registering a startup script that calls the "CloseMe" function on document.ready. When I do that, the code starts throwing javascript errors in JQuery that don't make sense. Like "Array is undefined" and "function is undefined" and "Date is undefined". EDIT: It does this when it hits the "window.parent.$...(close) statement. Note the alert right before that line. It correctly reports the id of the iframe.

I use that same "CloseMe" function from the Cancel button and everything works fine.

Edit: After ignoring all 25 or so errors in the debugger, the dialog DOES close.

Here is the javascript that opens the dialog:

```
function jQueryShowiFrame(url, title, reloadOnClose) {

    $('<iframe id="modalIframeId" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" src="' + url + '" />').load(function () {

        var width = $("#modalIframeId").contents().width();
        var height = $("#modalIframeId").contents().height();
        var paddingWidth = parseInt($("#modalIframeId").css("padding-left"), 10) + parseInt($("#modalIframeId").css("padding-right"), 10);

        // the sequence of these steps is important
        $("#modalIframeId").dialog("option", "width", (width + paddingWidth) + 'px');

        this.style.width = width + 'px';
        this.style.height = height + 'px';

        $("#modalIframeId").dialog("option", "position", "center");
    })
    .dialog({
        title: title,
        modal: true,
        close: function (ev, ui) {
            $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
            if (reloadOnClose) {
                location.reload();
            }
        },
        open: function (ev, ui) {
            //alert('x');
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the page markup:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" CssClass="BasicButton" Text="Save" />
<button type="button" id="btnClose" onclick="closeMe()" >Cancel</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function closeMe() {
        alert(window.frameElement.id);
        window.parent.$('#' + window.frameElement.id).dialog('close');
    }
</script>
```

Here is the code behind in the Save button click:

```
Dim scr As String = "$(document).ready(function () { closeMe(); });"
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, GetType(Page), Guid.NewGuid.ToString, scr, True)
```

Comment: May be you are Accessing the `frameElement.id` before it has been created. but in the close button `CloseMe` Works fine because the `frameElement` is Created.

Comment: I thought of that.  But when I put in the "alert(window.frameElement.id);" statement, it responds with the correct id.

Answer (score 0):

```
function jQueryShowiFrame(url, title, reloadOnClose) {

    $('<iframe id="modalIframeId" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" src="' + url + '" />').load(function () {

        var width = $("#modalIframeId").contents().width();
        var height = $("#modalIframeId").contents().height();
        var paddingWidth = parseInt($("#modalIframeId").css("padding-left"), 10) + parseInt($("#modalIframeId").css("padding-right"), 10);

        // the sequence of these steps is important
        $("#modalIframeId").dialog("option", "width", (width + paddingWidth) + 'px');

        this.style.width = width + 'px';
        this.style.height = height + 'px';

        $("#modalIframeId").dialog("option", "position", "center");
    })
    .dialog({
        title: title,
        modal: true,
        /*Add a Property */
        autoOpen : false, /* Instead of Calling 'CloseMe' */
        close: function (ev, ui) {
            $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
            if (reloadOnClose) {
                location.reload();
            }
        },
        open: function (ev, ui) {
            //alert('x');
        }
    });
}
```

Use `autoOpen:false` to prevent dialog been opened on start up. Use it instead of Calling the `CloseMe` function.

Hope it Helps.

Comment: Gokul - Thanks for responding quickly. Maybe I wasn't clear. jQueryShowiFrame() is just the function that originally loads the iframe. It does not get called again. So I can't re-call it from the page within the iframe.  Maybe I shouldn't have even included it. I just wanted to be complete.